# why wp_redirect() is showing me header information - headers already sent by ..?

Tags: wordpress

I am using custom template file called login.php for the Login page.

**Login.php code:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Login
 *
 * @package mytheme
 */

get_header();
the_post();
if(is_user_logged_in()){
    wp_redirect(site_url('/'));
    exit();
}
?>
```

Here, In this code, I am saying that if a user is already logged in then redirect to the site home page. But now it's showing error message like that:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\mytheme\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:242) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\themechum\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
    wp_redirect(site_url('/'));
    exit();
}
```

above get_header();

You can't use html tags above wp_redirect();

That's why you are getting the error 'headers already sent by'

Comment: Wow, great. Its working but why I need to use the function above get_header()?

Comment: It because get_header() is a header file which contains HTML and redirect function won't work if there is HTML above this function. So now HTML start after redirect function and it works